# How to restrict the user to login on multiple windows on same browser with different user types

Tags: php

The login page and their functionality works fine, but now I got a problem, when the user logged in with one account and after login he/she  open new window on same browser and type the loginviewcontroller.php  it is not showing the previous loggedin.php page and user can login with different accounts on two windows at the same time.

How can I restrict the user to login on multiple windows?

I need the functionality like gmail, if the user logged in once in a browser when he /she  open new window on same browser and type the www.gmail.com it shows the logged-in user information ... but not the gmail login page...

Please help me fix this problem.

**Here is the loginviewcontroller code**

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Fri, 4 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT");

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /// HTML code for login page....
} else {
    /// Here the values are posting...

    $Username  = $_POST['uname'];
    $Password  = $_POST['pwd'];
    $User_Type = $_POST['type'];
    session_start();

    If (!(empty($Username) && empty($Password) && empty($User_Type))) {

        $model = new UsersModel();

        $rowsCount = $model->checkUser($Username, $Password, $User_Type);

        if ($rowsCount != 0) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $Username;

            header("location:loggedin.php");

        } else {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Enter username and password correctly");
              window.location.href="LoginViewController.php";</script>';
        }
    }

   }
    ?>
```

**Here is the loggedin.php code**

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'true';

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: LoginViewController.php');
    exit();
}
echo '"<div style="background:white; text-align:right"> Login as:' . $_SESSION['user'] . '
       <a href="LogoutViewController.php" style="text-align:right">Logout</a></div>"';
?>
```

Comment: add this below `session_start(); $_SESSION['user'] = ''; $_SESSION['logged_in']='';`

Comment: What is the relationship between a user an an account? Or what you want is the same person cannot login twice using different accounts?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid my problem is after am logged in on one browser.....i opened new tab and i tried to call my index page then it is showing index page but not my logged in page i need that problem to fix...for eg:i want the functionality of gmail or facebook(without logging out your account in gmail or facebook it will show the same page in new tabs)

Comment: it because as i commented above your two session variables are always set on successful login so it will always be true on second login

Comment: put `session_start();` as the first line, even before your `header()` calls.

Comment: @ amigura yeah, my problem is after the user login and he/she tries to open the loginviewcontroller.php  in new window it is not showing the loggedin.php file

Comment: @Burhan Khalid i tried what you saying but it is not working ... and it is not showing loggedin.php after user logged in and opens the new tab and he typed the loginviewcontroller.php it is not showing the loggedin.php... file

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a variable in the user's session. You can just not allow the user to login again when this variable is set, since he'll be already logged in.

Also, don't forget to call [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)(). i.e. you can put this at the very top of your login page:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
  header("location:loggedin.php");
```

Comment: I tried that, but it is showing the loginviewcontrollerpage if i open on same browser in new window and the user can login.. with diff account..

Answer (score 0):

### In login Page

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: LoginViewController.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I already used that one ... in my code.. and my problem is not allow user to login with diff accounts with same browser windows..